# How to create temporary file from Chef template for use only during chef run

Tags: json, powershell, chef-infra, erb

I have a Chef recipe which enables an extension for my Windows VM in Microsoft Azure. This is done via a powershell_script resource. The PowerShell script uploads a JSON config file. What I would like to do is create a template for this config file and have this file temporarily created on the file system and call that JSON file from the PowerShell script. After the chef run is complete, delete that file. Sure, I can write all that logic into the script (create the file, then delete it) but my question is, is there a built-in mechanism in Chef which does this? How would I reference that temp location from my powershell script? I believe I can use:

```
Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
```

to set the scratch location but I don't know how to, or if I can, get my erb to be created in that location. This is a Windows box, though it probably doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Chef does not have any built-in mechanism to create temporary files. Are you sure you must delete it after every run? Why cannot it stay?

```
my_file_path = ::File.join( Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'my_file.json' )
template my_file_path do
  [...]
  notifies :run, "powershell_script[upload #{my_file_path}]"
end

powershell_script "upload #{my_file_path}" do
  action :nothing
  code "Upload #{my_file_path}" #just an example
end
```

The above code creates the file from template in Chef::Config[:file_cache_path] directory, but does not delete it afterwords. This way you can configure your recipe so, that it does not execute your powershell scripts every time, but only when the file has changed.

If you definitely want to delete it, then just add

```
template my_file_path do
  action :delete
end
```

to the end of the recipe. But this will make all the 3 resources (create file, run script, delete file) be executed on every Chef run, which is not a very good thing.